# Adding container's parent to itself

Tags: java, swing

Имеется следующий код:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main {

    private static JLabel portText = new JLabel("Port:");
    private static JLabel brokerAddressText = new JLabel("Broker ip address:");
    private static JLabel topicText = new JLabel("Topic");
    private static JLabel messageText = new JLabel("Message:");
    private static JTextField port = new JTextField(4);
    private static JTextField brokerAddress = new JTextField(10);
    private static JTextField topic = new JTextField(10);
    private static JTextField message = new JTextField(20);
    private static JButton connect = new JButton("Connect");
    private static JButton disconnect = new JButton("Disconnect");
    private static JButton subscribe = new JButton("Subscribe");
    private static JButton unsubscribe = new JButton("Unsubscribe");
    private static JButton publish = new JButton("Publish");
    private static int iPort;
    private static String sIp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = getFrame();

        connect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try{
                    iPort = Integer.parseInt(port.getText());
                    sIp = brokerAddress.getText();
                }catch (NumberFormatException exc){
                    System.out.println("Wrong port input");
                }
            }
        });



    }

    private static JFrame getFrame(){
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        JPanel jPanel = (JPanel) jFrame.getContentPane();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setBounds(750,250,500,500);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.add(jPanel);
        jFrame.setTitle("MQTT client");
        portText.setLocation(10,10);
        jPanel.add(portText);
        port.setLocation(10,30);
        jPanel.add(port);
        jPanel.add(brokerAddressText);
        jPanel.add(brokerAddress);
        jPanel.add(connect);
        jPanel.add(disconnect);
        jPanel.add(topicText);
        jPanel.add(topic);
        jPanel.add(subscribe);
        jPanel.add(unsubscribe);
        jPanel.add(messageText);
        jPanel.add(message);
        jPanel.add(publish);
        jPanel.revalidate();
        return jFrame;
    }

}
```

При компиляции выдает ошибку:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding
>   container's parent to itself  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.checkAddToSelf(Container.java:497)    at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1110)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:1025)  at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:553)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:432)   at
>   com.company.Main.getFrame(Main.java:50)   at
>   com.company.Main.main(Main.java:26)

Понимаю, что скорее всего это из-за строк

```
JPanel jPanel = (JPanel) jFrame.getContentPane();
jFrame.add(jPanel);
```

Но в таком случае, не понимаю, как добавить панельку тогда

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше всего для JFrame создавать отдельный класс с удобным конструктором:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
  }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame {
  MyFrame() {

  }
}
```

Теперь можно указать основные настройки в конструкторе:

setVisible(); лучше всего ставить самым последним;

а также в конце самые не проблемные функции как размер,локация,фулскрин,выход,рамки...

название title (super) лучше всего в самом начале конструктора

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {
  MyFrame() {
    super("MQTT client");



    setBounds(400,400,400,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

теперь панель и layout (расположение) основных элементов интерфейса (кнопки и строки тд)

GridLayout,BoxLayout,GroupLayout,BorderLayout,CardLayout и другие

в GridLayout элементы распалогаються в сетке 3 на 3

```
  MyFrame() {
    super("MQTT client");

    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(jPanel);

    jPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));



    setBounds(400,400,400,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

теперь можно создавать всё остальное

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
  }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame {

  private static JLabel portText = new JLabel("Port:");
  private static JLabel brokerAddressText = new JLabel("Broker ip address:");
  private static JLabel topicText = new JLabel("Topic");
  private static JLabel messageText = new JLabel("Message:");
  private static JTextField port = new JTextField(4);
  private static JTextField brokerAddress = new JTextField(10);
  private static JTextField topic = new JTextField(10);
  private static JTextField message = new JTextField(20);
  private static JButton connect = new JButton("Connect");
  private static JButton disconnect = new JButton("Disconnect");
  private static JButton subscribe = new JButton("Subscribe");
  private static JButton unsubscribe = new JButton("Unsubscribe");
  private static JButton publish = new JButton("Publish");


  MyFrame() {
    super("MQTT client");

    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(jPanel);

    jPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

    jPanel.add(portText);
    jPanel.add(port);
    jPanel.add(brokerAddressText);
    jPanel.add(brokerAddress);
    jPanel.add(connect);
    jPanel.add(disconnect);
    jPanel.add(topicText);
    jPanel.add(topic);
    jPanel.add(subscribe);
    jPanel.add(unsubscribe);
    jPanel.add(messageText);
    jPanel.add(message);
    jPanel.add(publish);

    setBounds(400,400,400,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

теперь осталось только настроить их местоположение 
вот видео о том как это сделать в gridLayout

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cuVqLxNBbc